# Getting an value error from extended user model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a form that allows me to update an extended user model, see my views below

```
def employee(request, pk):

    employee= Employee.objects.get(id=pk)
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
    Employee = EmployeeProfileForm(instance=employee)


    if 'edit_employee' in request.POST:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user_form = UserForm(request.POST,instance=user)
            employee_form = EmployeeProfileForm(request.POST,instance=user.employee)

            if user_form.is_valid() and employee_form.is_valid():
                user = user_form.save()
                employee = employee_form.save(commit=False)
                employee.user = user
                employee.save()
                return redirect('/')

                return render(request, 'accounts/new_employee_profile.html', {'user_form': user_form,'employee_form':employee_form})
```

models.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None,is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have email address")
        user_obj = self.model(email = self.normalize_email(email))
        if not password:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")

        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)

        return user_obj

    def create_staffuser(self,email,password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password,is_staff=True)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(email, password=password, is_staff=True, is_admin=True)

        return user



class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # email and password are required by default
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active


class Employee(models.Model):


    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    birth_year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    profession = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


    def clean_password2(self):

        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):

        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class EmployeeProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

template

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form action="" method="POST">

                  {{user_form.as_p|crispy}}
                {{employee_form.as_p|crispy }}

                <hr>
                <input type="submit" name="Edit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting an error below based on my views as follows

```
The view accounts.views.EmployeeProfile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I have a template before the accessing the template to update the form as follows

```
<td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" name= "edit_employee" href="{% url 'employee_profile' employee.id %}">Edit</a></td>
```

How will I have to change the code shown, in order to update or edit my form?

Given that the form needs to be updated and submitted at the same time as it is a extended user model which is the User model and the employee model.

Answer (score 1):

every view must return a `HttpResponse`. The error you are getting is self-explanatory.

here you are getting this error because you have not explicitly returned anything ins case of your if statements are false.

if these cases are false, by default `None` will be returned, which is not an expected return data type for Django views.

explicitly returning `HttpResponse` in case of following if cases  will solve the issue

```
if 'edit_employee' in request.POST:
        if request.method == 'POST':
        .
        .
        if user_form.is_valid() and employee_form.is_valid():
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view

Comment: Thanks, I got the form to appear on the template, however if I were to change something in the form, it does not to save the changes.  How do I get to change the code shown above in order to allow the forms to save the changes.

Comment: you don't have to change the form, you have to handle the case such as if the form is not valid what should be returned,